# Can I use a Blue Horseshoe Balloon to make the Bundle of Balloons?

Tags: terraria

I am having trouble finding a *Blizzard in a Bottle*, so I have considered making a *Blue Horseshoe Balloon* while I wait to make the *Bundle of Balloons*, as it can negate fall damage. Since I only have one *Shiny Red Balloon* and only one *Cloud in a Balloon*, I wanted to know if I could use the crafted *Blue Horseshoe Balloon* in the recipe for the *Bundle of Balloons*.

Comment: A "*Lucky Sandstorm in a Bottle*" is just a [Sandstorm in a Bottle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Sandstorm_in_a_Bottle) with the Lucky prefix. Are you referring to a [Yellow Horseshoe Balloon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Yellow_Horseshoe_Balloon), which is what you get by combining a Sandstorm in a Balloon with a Lucky Horseshoe?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion I may have caused, I apparently don't know how to type the words in my head

Comment: Uh... Once again, are you referring to what you get for combining a Lucky Horseshoe with a Cloud in a Balloon? That'd be a [Blue Horseshoe Balloon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Blue_Horseshoe_Balloon).

Comment: @MrLemon, guess who derped again and doesn't know how to speak (I dare you)

Comment: If you're looking to save on accessory slots, you might consider combining the Lucky Horseshoe with an Obsidian Skull, as the only other items you can combine with the Horseshoe are Balloon items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

You cannot later use the Blue Horseshoe Balloon as part of crafting a Bundle of Balloons, nor can you return the Blue Horseshoe Balloon to its constituent parts.

Source: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bundle_of_Balloons

Comment: Also the sandstorm in a bottle is the rarest of the components for the bundle of balloons, so using it up in something else is, perhaps, a bad idea. Most worlds have the other two, but only a few worlds will have the sandstorm. Not really an answer to part of the question, but a commonly associated piece of optimization thought.